# AngularJS throwing errors root path

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am having trouble finding why my application is throwing errors at one path but not the other.

My angular application functions fine at the following URL with my default servlet.

```
http://localhost:8080/#/
```

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cr</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I would expect with the below servlet mapping that I should be able to access another application with the following url.

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/resources/admin/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However it throws the following errors constantly until I pause the page in my chrome debugger.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The admin application however does function if I go to the following URL.

```
http://localhost:8080/admin#/
```

For reference here is my app.js

```
'use strict';
var AdminApp = angular.module('AdminApp', ['AdminApp.services'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
// default route
        $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'resources/admin/views/dashboard.jsp', controller: 'DashboardCtrl'}).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    }]);
```

main.js

```
//Dashboard Controller
AdminApp.controller('DashboardCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

service.js

```
var service = angular.module("AdminApp.services", ['ngResource']);
```

Note:  I know that the app, main, and service are not actually doing anything, I am just trying to get the shell working before I start extending it with valid data.

Here is the order in which I initiate everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I changed my web.xml to below it functioned as expected. I still do not know why it was throwing errors.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/resources/admin/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```